# qgis2web Polygon on hover effect

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I want to add mouse on-hover effect when I am about to select a particular property Lot (section of land). E.g. highlight and change its background color. Is this even possible and where to modifiy the code exported from qgis2web package?

I found a style property variable inside [layer_name]_style.js under 'style foler' but not sure if this is supposed to be the one to change.

Answer (score 1):

That feature is available in qgsi2web.  Under the appearance tab there is a check box for "Highlight on Hover".  When you add a check mark to that option and export the map, the feature should be highlighted when your mouse hovers over it.

[image: Qgis2Web Appearance Tab]

Comment: thank you very much!! I will try this out :)